# Aspx form doesn't pass data to code behind file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I'm try to send the data in email field to the code and then work with it. However, the data never reaches the code, I've tried even setting breakpoints and it never halts at the breakpoint.

Form-

```
<form class="cd-form"  runat="server"  >

<label class="cd-label" for="email" runat="server">Console</label>

<input type="text" class="cd-email" name="email" id="email" runat="server" placeholder="Enter address to test connection">

<input type="submit" class="cd-submit" value="submit" runat="server" id="submit" onserverclick="Accept"  />

<div class="cd-loading"></div>

</form>
```

Code behind file-

```
protected void Accept(object sender,EventArgs e)
{

    String a = email.Value;

    if( email.Value == "a@a.com" )

    {

        Response.Redirect("README.aspx");

    }

 }
```

Comment: you are mixing plain html form elements with ASP serverside processing. I think you need to use `<ASP:TextBox runat="server" ...>` consistently, for the postback mechanism with ASP event handlers to work.

Comment: I'll give that a shot too, then would the CSS styles work with those too?

Comment: yes, use the `CssClass` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Email.value
```

To `email.text`

Answer (score 0):

Change in your line
 String a = email .Value ;
To
String a email.text;
protected void Accept(object sender,EventArgs e)
{

```
String a = email.text;

if( email.text== "a@a.com" )

{

    Response.Redirect("README.aspx");

}
```

}